# Is this code for "rotating matrix" smart or naive? O(1) approach

Tags: java, algorithm

I just came across matrix rotation on some random situation. The most obvious approach would be mapping elements from an (n x m) matrix A to A' where A' is the new matrix with (m x n). Here is some pseudo-code, of O(nm), for this obvious method.

```
def rotateRight(A[1..n][1..m]): // O(nm)
    let A'[1..m][1..n] be a new matrix
    for i from 1 to n:
        for j from 1 to m:
            A'[n-j][i] = A[i][j] // not sure if this is right
    return A'
```

The code above looks typical. However, after some thought, I actually think that we can do better.

A matrix can only have 4 orientation(north, east, south, west) however you rotate it. Here is an illustration:
[image: Illustration]

By encapsulating the internal representation of the matrix and providing getter method for elements, we could actually implement rotate like the following.

```
class Matrix{
     private (final) elements[n][m];

     private getElemStrategies = [getElemNorth, getElemEast, getElemSouth, getElemWest];
     private currentStrategy = 0;

     public getElem(x, y){
         return getElemStrategies[currentStrategy];             
     }

     public rotateRight(){ // O(1)
         currentStrategy = (currentStrategy + 1) % 4
     }
}
```

Here `getElemNorth`, `getElemEast`, `getElemSouth`, `getElemWest` are just getter method corresponds to the current orientation of the matrix. Specifically, `getElemEast` would be something like:

```
def getElemEast(x, y)
    return this.elements[n-j][i]
```

This method takes O(1) which actually works. I think it is pretty cool but not sure about its correctness. Is there a name for this method?

Comment: Can you explain what exactly is O(1)? Which algorithm or operation? Here you explain how to get an element of a "rotated" matrix, but you did not rotate it yet, did you? P.S.: I did not check for correctness.

Comment: specifically the rotateRight() method.

Comment: Well, as far as I can see, it just sets the strategy, but does not rotate yet.

Comment: This is basically just lazy evaluation.  You're deferring the cost til later, which is cheaper assuming you do few lookups.

Comment: This is a pretty standard technique, but I am not sure if it has a standard name (I can't think of one). As examples, `numpy.fliplr` (http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.fliplr.html) and transpose come to mind.

Comment: You are right, indirect access through a strategy will make the *rotate* O(1), at the cost of slowing lookups a bit. It also saves memory. The question is, have you gained anything, overall? How often do you rotate vs. read all values? Is memory an issue? Generally speaking, the answer is *nothing gained*, unless memory is an issue, which means the benefit is not the O(?) performance, but the lower memory footprint.

Comment: How is this deferring cost? As far as I see, this method doesn't limit the matrix to perform any action as far as we have `getElem` and `setElem`.

Comment: @JasonYu It doesn't limit any action, but it does slow the actions down a bit. Indirection through strategy plus index calculations. Small cost * n * m. Is it more or less than cost of copying? Depends on rotate vs lookup ratio.

Comment: @Andreas The time we are slowing down lookups should be of O(c) which shouldn't matter comparing to O(nm).

Comment: @Andreas I see what you mean! :) But if we are talking about matrix of a very large size, I guess this method would be better?

Comment: Memory-wise? Yes. Performance-wise? Depends. Only performance testing of actual workload can say for sure. Down-side (benefit?) is that changing values in the rotated matrix also changes original. Issue? Maybe.

Comment: You are mixing a bit two things here. Rotating a matrix means rotating or accessing each element of a matrix. What you presented is access only one element of a rotated matrix. That's not an algorithm for matrix rotation, that's accessing an element of a rotated matrix. Accessing an element can always be done in O(1). If you try to access each element of the rotated matrix you find yourself executing `n*m` O(1). I would not say it is more efficient for a matrix rotation. It's merely good if you want to select few elements of a rotated matrix.

Comment: @Elyasin no offense, but I have no idea what do you mean by "What you presented is access only one element of a rotated matrix.". My implementation allow access to each and every element of the rotated matrix.

Comment: It allows access to any element, but that's all. Where is your algorithm that takes as input a matrix and returns the rotated matrix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a pretty standard technique.

For a good exposition, I'd recommend reading up on how NumPy strides work, for example [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.ndarray.html).

One thing to bear in mind with this is that locality of reference matters: it is much cheaper to scan consecutive locations in memory than to read the same amount of data scattered all over the place. Depending on what it is that you do with your matrix, this could negate the savings gained by the constant-time rotations.